# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) error still after adding android:exported=false

Tags: android, xamarin.android, intentfilter, android-12, targetsdkversion

I upgraded the project to targetSDKVersion="31" and installed that version in VS.

I get the following error when trying to run project with a phone with Android 12:

```
Error       ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl803710359.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #93): crc6496621e99a539ca61.SomeAppLaunchActivity: 

Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
```

I also tried the instructions from:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk
One of the main things it mentions is adding to the manifest file the android:exported="false" which I did, as seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.arc.ourproject.something" android:versionName="126.01.0" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="107">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />       
    <uses-permissions here....>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <application android:label="Project" android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/OURTheme" android:icon="@drawable/our_icon_180px" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:exported="false">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AppLaunchActivity.cs has:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, AutoVerify = true, Categories = new[]
    {
        Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    }
```

Comment: Please try the updated part in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, all the activities, services and broadcast receivers which has the intent filter in the app which target version is Api 31 need to declare the `android: exported=`. You can declare it in the Attribute, such as  `[Activity(Exported = false)]` or in the AndroidManifest.xml, such as:

```
<activity android:enabled="true" android:name=".ActivityName" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="...."/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

According to the error message, there is an activity named SomeAppLaunchActivity in your app need to declare the `android:exported`. If it is created by yourself, you declare it use the method above.

Or it may be created by the nuget package in your app, if so, you have to check the version of the package and update to the version which support the android Api 31.

**Update**

Please declare the AppLaunchActivity's exported such as:

```
 [Activity(Exported=true)]
 [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, AutoVerify = true, Categories = new[]
{
    Intent.CategoryDefault,
    Intent.CategoryBrowsable
}
 public class AppLaunchActivity : Activity{}
```

Comment: Thanks, this got rid of the error. I read the documentation on the google android site, but I am still a little confused on true vs false for exported. it says to choose true if its going to pull from another app. I am adding this to the applaunchactivity with the intentfilters shown above. Should this be exported = false?

Comment: The `exported` property depends on if you want the other apps can start the applaunchactivity or not. If the value is true, means the applaunchactivity can be invoked by the other apps and if the value is false, means it can just be invoked in your app. @angleUr